# Editing encrypted data in a PHP session

Tags: php, security, session, encryption

I'm building a password manager in PHP where the user can store and access a set of passwords using a master password. The database is a simple XML file, encrypted using mcrypt and stored on the disk.

**Edit:** Each user has its own database file.

The problem is: When the user edits one of his passwords, the database must be decrypted, changed, and encrypted again. Every time the user edits something, I have to know his master password to access the database, so I have to temporarily store the password somewhere on the server or the user has type it in for every change.

I know that storing the password in a session variable can cause security problems, so is there another, more secure way to do it?

*Note*: I don't have root or physical access to the server hosting the project, so I can't change any configuration.

Comment: why are you not using a real data base?

Comment: why do you need the master password to access the database? is there not simply a user id that can be used to find the database and open it?

Comment: @Dagon, The only other option I have is MySQL, but I think that wouldn't solve the encryption problem.

Comment: should mean easier access to individual variables, no need to decode the whole thing every time.

Comment: @dqhendricks I should have added that to the question: Each user has its own database file.
I can find that file with an ID, as you suggested, but the file is encrypted with the user's master password.

Comment: perhaps you shouldn't be encrypting it with the users master password. and Dagon is right, you should really be using a database for this.

Comment: But I have to encrypt it somehow. Storing passwords in plain text in a database (XML or MySQL) is not secure enough. Maybe I could encrypt the whole DB with one password, but then both password and data would be stored in the same remote location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A totally different option is to never have the plaintext stored on the server (neither on disk or in memory). The JavaScript you serve to the client could be used to encrypt/decrypt the data entirely in the client's browser, based on the master password they enter (so the master password would also never be transmitted- remember a secret between two people is only secret if one is dead! ;).

On the server, you would only store the encrypted versions of the data. The data would have been encrypted by the time they get POSTed to the site. The data is still encrypted when the site servers it to the browser.

This solves a *lot* of the security issues. An *actively* malicious web server could still compromise security, but only when the user is actively loading the initial page with the JavaScript. A passive attacker (even if they could see the server's full system memory at all times) would not be able to do anything to compromise security.

For the user to login to the site (to then be able to access the data cypher text), you could either use a separate password from the master password, *or* have the JavaScript hash (with a salt!) the master password before transmitting it to the server (which you should still store hashed and salted again).

Answer (score 1):

Once you have master password stored on disk, any encryption is totally useless and it just decreases performance.

If someone just pulled out HDD during session lifetime he could easily use that password to open file.

If you get rough admin, you're just ... you're just done, because he can just store password before file opening. So I assume admin is on your side and you have system well configured.

Fist thing you can do is [disk encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_encryption). This would actually increase security a lot. If anyone stole your HDD with plaintext password in session he wouldn't be able to read it anyway.

Than using HTTPS... This should be mandatory when working with passwords and whole your initiative is useless if you're using just HTTP.

In php... I'm not sure whether you can do anything. But when you're using https you can do this:

- store password in `$pass`
- generate temporary random encryption key (`$rand`)
- store password encrypted by `$rand` (I used just XOR)
- store `$rand` into `$_COOKIE` variable
- use `$_COOKIE` value to decrypt master password on every request

Example:

```
$pass = 'iddqd';
$rand = 'abcde';
echo base64_encode( $pass^$rand); // CAYHFQE=
$_COOKIE['phrase'] = $rand;
$_SESSION['password'] = base64_encode( $pass^$rand);
unset( $pass);

// And on every other request:
$pass = $_COOKIE['phrase'] ^ base64_decode($_SESSION['password'])
```

What's the added value? Storing password in plain text relies just on authenticated disk access.

Generating temporary phrase and storing it in user browser (and only on user side) makes it rely on authenticated disk access + cookie value generated on user authentication (which should be hard to spoof).

And one more thing, you shouldn't have to worry about sending phrase in each request (you may change it every 10-100-1000 requests) when you're using https.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider not using the password as your direct encryption key.  Try doing something like this:

```
$_SESSION['myKey'] = md5($_POST['userName'] .$_POST['password']); //create a hash based on multiple predictable criteria
```

...and then use $_SESSION['myKey'] instead of the password.  That way when you can keep their key in session state without it being exposed.

Comment: This would protect the master password some (much smaller window it's visible), but it wouldn't really improve the security of the encrypted data itself.

Comment: I agree. the encrypted data is only as secure as the key and encryption algorithm.  That said, I'm only forwarding this as a better way to get his app to run, not my preferred method.  I agree with everyone else that it should go in a DB.